# How to get properly entity names using gmsh fortran api?

Tags: api, fortran, entity, names, gmsh

gmsh: When I import the name of my entities using the Fortran API (i.e., with the call gmsh%model%getentityname routine), there seems to be an issue with the character format. I get unreadable entity names, even though these entities do have names. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Im trying to use gmsh fortran api

Comment: I think we need more details or information - what do you mean by 'issue with the character format'? What do they actually look like, and what do you expect them to look like? Remember that we may not be experts in gmsh.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We really need more detail. How exactly do you get unreadable names? Please show an example according to [mcve]. Remember, this is a general programing site. I do use gmsh from time to time and used it even today, but have never done so in Fortran. We can try to help but we need to see exactly what you tried and which exact errors you got.